# StreamReader.ReadToEnd() fails to retrieve the whole stream

Tags: streamreader, memorystream

I am obtaining a memorystream that represents an attachment. The attachment is an HTML document like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">    
<HTML>    
...    
</HTML>    
<p><img border="0" src="http://www.somewebsite.com/mcv18/mapp_v50/images/mcrptgenlogo.jpg"></p>
```

The code I am using is:

```
Using strm As New MemoryStream()
   anAttachment.Save(strm)
   strm.Position = 0
   Using sr As New StreamReader(strm)
     Dim attachmentAsString As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
   End Using
End Using
```

The `anAttachment.Save(strm)` is where I am obtaining the attachment's content using a third party library Attachment class instance. Anyway, What I am ending up in the attachmentAsString it is just a "<".

If I use this code:

```
anAttachment.Save("C:\Temp\Attachement.tmp"
attachmentAsString = File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\Attachement.tmp")
```

I get the exact same result. "<"

When I check the file on disk I can see the whole Html document.
In the first chunk code if I check the strm.Position after the ReadToEnd call it is all the way to the end of the stream.
I can read bytes individually and it seems to advance the position every time but it returns some integers which I am not very fond of.

Can someone tell me what can be done to have this working?